# Side navigation not closing in React, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

It opens correctly when I click on a card but then I can't seem to close the menu when I click on the x. You can find an example on w3schools, most of the code is from there. I added a link at the bottom of the code.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
        this.openNav = this.openNav.bind(this)
        this.closeNav = this.closeNav.bind(this)
      }
  openNav() {


    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
  }

  closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";

  }
```

```
<div id="mySidenav" className="sidenav">
                    <a
                      className="closebtn"
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.closeNav();
                        return false;
                      }}
                    >
                      &times;
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                    <a href="#">Clients</a>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                  </div>
```

```
 <div className="card" onClick={() => this.openNav()}>
 ...
 </div>
```

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

This is what I used https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav

Comment: Can you post more of your code or a link to a sandbox? It is hard to tell what is going wrong from what you have posted. It seems to work fine here https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-flower-hsnz8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an old school method.In react you should write that code like that:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           isSideBarOpen: false
        };
        this.openNav = this.openNav.bind(this)
        this.closeNav = this.closeNav.bind(this)
      }
  openNav() {
        this.setState({isSideBarOpen: true});
  }

  closeNav() {
        this.setState({isSideBarOpen: false});
  }
```

and html part should be like this:

```
<div id="mySidenav" className={this.state.isSideBarOpen?"sideBarShow":"sideBarHide"}>
   <a className="closebtn" onClick={() => {this.closeNav();}}>
      &times;
   </a>
   <a href="#">About</a>
   <a href="#">Services</a>
   <a href="#">Clients</a>
   <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div className={this.state.isSideBarOpen?"sideBarOpenButtonHide":"sideBarOpenButtonShow" onClick={() => this.openNav()}>
   ...
</div>
```

After that you can arrange css codes accordingly I am not sure but you should use transitions for animations.In case you don't know `?` and `:` expression these are same with if and else logic, if the statement before `?` sign is true then js pick first part (after `?` sign to `:` sign) else js pick second part (after `:` part).
And finally css file should be like this:

```
.sideBarShow {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

.sideBarHide {
  width: 0px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}
.sideBarOpenButtonShow {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

.sideBarOpenButtonHide {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried it this way and still when I click on the x it would not close, the state doesn't seem to change either since the class stays the same. https://prnt.sc/rdau7z I placed a console log in closeNav and it works but the class doesn't change on the div. https://prnt.sc/rdauq8

Comment: Hmm interesting, it should have work .Does isSideBarOpen change? Please console it and check setState whether works correctly.

Comment: It didn't, however I found the answer because thanks to the comments on this post. Calling a function that sets the state didn't work when I clicked the x to close the button. But calling this.setState({
                          isSideBarOpen: !this.state.isSideBarOpen
                        }); directly worked.

Comment: happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, react components don't tend to access the DOM with methods like `getElementById`.

Instead, your components should hold their own state, and then their UI should reflect that state.

We can simplify your example this with `useState`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [isNavOpen, setIsNavOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`sidenav ${isNavOpen ? "open" : ""}`}>
        <button className="closebtn" onClick={() => setIsNavOpen(!isNavOpen)}>
          &times;
        </button>
        <a href="/about">About</a>
        <a href="/services">Services</a>
        <a href="/client">Clients</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsNavOpen(!isNavOpen)}>Toggle nav</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Calling `useState(false)` returns an array of two things:

- a simple piece of state, `isNavOpen`, which can either be `true` or `false`. (We have initialised it to `false`)
- a function `setIsNavOpen` which can update the `isNavOpen` state with a new value.

---

Now we can easily toggle this state variable with `setIsNavOpen(!isNavOpen)` whenever we want to open or close the nav.

---

Finally, we can make use of this state variable in the UI.

`` <div className={ `sidenav ${isNavOpen ? "open" : "closed"}` }> ``

If `isNavOpen` = true, it renders `<div class="sidenav open">`

If `isNavOpen` = false, it renders `<div class="sidenav closed">`